# comma use in a definition

Tags: comma, punctuation

The following is a definition of the verb "schaffen." I'm wondering if the comma means something like "oder." I'm curious about whether this is a feature of definitions or prose in general.

> erfolgreich hinter sich bringen, beenden

Comment: The practice is common in dictionaries because dictionaries are huge. Using ',' in place of 'oder' saves only three characters, but across 70,000 definitions, that adds up.

Comment: Is the comma use an exclusive feature of definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in definitions in a dictionary, a comma is a common way to separate alternative paraphrases.

See for example any entry in Grimm's Wörterbuch:
https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB

Wiktionary, DWDS and others also use this:

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schaffen

https://www.dwds.de/wb/schaffen

Comment: Thank you. I'm only a beginner. Could you cite a contemporary example?

Comment: I have added links to "schaffen" in the modern dictionaries I mentioned, but you can basically take any dictionary for German, English, French, Spanisch, Italian and other European languages and find that use. It's very basic.

Comment: English tends to use semicolons to separate paraphrases, and it wouldn't use commas with two juxtaposed synonymous verbs that each can be used to define an expression.

Comment: It's a convention that seemingly depends more on the dictionary than the language. The printed English "Roget's thesaurus" I have here only uses commas. Oxford dictionaries tend to use semicolons, which makes a lot of sense, but I can also find the use of commas. OpenThesaurus uses the centered dot (·).

Comment: Thesauri are different from ordinary dictionaries. Could you offer some examples of English definitions where commas are used to introduce paraphrases?

Comment: Sorry, no, this is becoming ridiculous. As I mentioned, I saw it in a printed version of the Oxford dictionary, but I have no interest in convincing you, and this is offtopic in German language SE.

Comment: Well, it was you who introduced the statement, "you can basically take any dictionary for German, **English**, French, Spanisch, Italian and other European languages and find that use. It's very basic." I'd say you might see commas only when the definition contains two or more words each of which is a synonym that constitutes the definition itself, but the situation is different from what we see in German dictionaries, where the comma is used to separate a **component** of a definition from an alternative of that component.

Comment: Please see this thread on Reddit, which shows the particular use of the comma is unnatural in English definitions. https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/13w6apt/comment/jm9vcgv/?context=3